# How to track down a Spanish/Latin American soldier that fought in wars internationally (18th/19th century)?

Tags: military, 19th-century, 18th-century

The details are scant, but I hope it's enough to get the community interested and a clear answer emerge (there can't be that many people who fit the bill?).

I read a long time ago about a famous Spanish/Latin American soldier who fought in several major conflicts in the 18th or 19th century: he fought in Latin America (maybe with Jose de San Martin?), in the US, and in Europe. I'm not clear if he was a mercenary of sorts, or just chased after battle, but I remember being amazed at the fact that this one man managed to be a part of the major military conflicts at the time.

I'm hoping to find a good biography--I know it exists because I read about this person in a major media company: something like 'the not-so-famous soldier/general that shaped world history' (very loose paraphrase). At the time I found some books on Amazon but life happened and I lost track of them.

Comment: You should accept your own answer as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Writing out the question somehow jogged my memory and I found him: [Francisco de Miranda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francisco_de_Miranda).

From Wikipedia:

"Miranda led a romantic and adventurous life in the general political and intellectual climate that emerged from the Age of Enlightenment that influenced all of the Atlantic Revolutions. **He participated in three major historical and political movements of his time: the American Revolutionary War, the French Revolution and the Spanish American wars of independence.** He described his experiences over this time in his journal, which reached to 63 bound volumes."

Here's the biography in question-- "[Francisco de Miranda: A Transatlantic Life in the Age of Revolution.](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1874127.Francisco_de_Miranda)"

And Spanish speakers can find digitized versions of his journal free (legal) [here](http://www.cervantesvirtual.com/buscador/?q=francisco%20de%20miranda).